# bigcommerce email forward through javascript/php

Tags: email, bigcommerce

Is it possible to forward a email when someone register on bigcommerce.
So when a customer register the admin must be notified by a email.

Comment: can you please show your effort

Comment: i've talked with the bigcommerce support they didnt know how to do they wanted me to pay programmers to do . so i researched on the internet how to do it but didnt find it

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way to do this would be to use Webhooks when a customer record is created.
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks-getting-started